# Detects only one element from the config

Tags: java, bukkit

I have a code that checks the number of items in crafting for a given object from the config. Only that it detects only object 1 for checking, and then nothing, as if there was no recipe.

I will add that when I comment on this function, craft crafting works one by one normally. So what can the problem be?

```
@Deprecated
@EventHandler
public void prepare(PrepareItemCraftEvent e) {
    for(String crafter : cfg.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("craftings").getKeys(false)) {
        ConfigurationSection s = cfg.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("craftings." + crafter);
        ItemStack its = new ItemStack(Material.getMaterial(s.getInt("item")), 1, (byte) s.getInt("data"));
        if(e.getInventory().getResult() !=null) {
            if(e.getInventory().getResult().getType().equals(its.getType())) {
                if(e.getInventory().getItem(1) != null) {
                    if(e.getInventory().getItem(1).getAmount() == s.getInt(".items.iloscA")
                            && e.getInventory().getItem(2).getAmount() == s.getInt("items.iloscB")
                            && e.getInventory().getItem(3).getAmount() == s.getInt("items.iloscC")
                            && e.getInventory().getItem(4).getAmount() == s.getInt("items.iloscD")
                            && e.getInventory().getItem(5).getAmount() == s.getInt("items.iloscE")
                            && e.getInventory().getItem(6).getAmount() == s.getInt("items.iloscF")
                            && e.getInventory().getItem(7).getAmount() == s.getInt("items.iloscG")
                            && e.getInventory().getItem(8).getAmount() == s.getInt("items.iloscH")
                            && e.getInventory().getItem(9).getAmount() == s.getInt("items.iloscI")) {
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        e.getInventory().setResult(new ItemStack(Material.AIR, 1));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

config.yml

`craftings:
  creeper:
    item: 383
    data: 50
    items:
      A: 289
      dataA: 0
      iloscA: 64
      B: 19
      dataB: 0
      iloscB: 32
      C: 289
      dataC: 0
      iloscC: 64
      D: 12
      dataD: 0
      iloscD: 64
      E: 344
      dataE: 0
      iloscE: 1
      F: 12
      dataF: 0
      iloscF: 64
      G: 289
      dataG: 0
      iloscG: 64
      H: 19
      dataH: 0
      iloscH: 32
      I: 289
      dataI: 0
      iloscI: 64
  slime:
    item: 383
    data: 55
    items:
      A: 165
      dataA: 0
      iloscA: 4
      B: 19
      dataB: 0
      iloscB: 32
      C: 165
      dataC: 0
      iloscC: 4
      D: 19
      dataD: 0
      iloscD: 32
      E: 344
      dataE: 0
      iloscE: 1
      F: 19
      dataF: 0
      iloscF: 32
      G: 165
      dataG: 0
      iloscG: 4
      H: 19
      dataH: 0
      iloscH: 32
      I: 165
      dataI: 0
      iloscI: 4`

Comment: @Squiddie Could you give me an example please?

Comment: I recommend this API for configs: https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/yamler.315/
You can load a config file directly into an object.